# Get the index of the parent element, by finding the childs data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

Is it possible by knowing the child's data-id to do a find().index() on the parent?
my code is as such:

```
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 38640px; left: 0px; display: block;">
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 280px;">
        <div class="itemchild" data-remid="67">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 280px;">
        <div class="itemchild" data-remid="135">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item" style="width: 280px;">
        <div class="itemchild" data-remid="136">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to get the index of the **itemchild** element, that contains a chile with a specific **data-remid**

something like: `.find("[data-remid='" + ID + "'"]).parent().index();`

Comment: Are you getting any error? Add completed javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't handled the quotes correctly while making selector. Use:

```
$("[data-remid=" + ID + "]").parent().index();
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/epp9jj3e/)**